# Discord.js - Guild ID is undefined even though definition is there

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Making a discord bot. Everything works fine, except the one command of `-!prefix`. `-!` being the prefix, and the command taking the args and changing the prefix of the server.

Before I go into detail about this while thing, here's the bot's code, maybe I simply did something wrong in the consts: [Hastebin Link](https://hastebin.com/irocuwuduw.js)

The error here is in line 52, according to the console: [Console Log](https://hastebin.com/ugaciyuwoz.tex)

I'm confused as to what to do with this being "undefined." I've tried using the `message.guild.id` property as the variable, and also the one shown on the code. I've tried moving it to multiple places, although the only place it even registers is INSIDE of the prefix command (which is currently broken because of this error.)

Anyone have any fixes? I'm not that much of an expert in the whole JavaScript thing, as I came over from Python and regular Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code at `line 52` is currently:

```js
var server = bot.guilds.get(message.author).id
```

You're currently passing a `User` object into the `.get()` which should recieve an `id or snowflake`.

With this in mind, your code should look like:

```js
var server = bot.guilds.get(message.guild.id).id;
```

However, this is a bit excessive because you can simply shorten it to:

```js
var server = message.guild.id;
```

Now you said that you've

> tried using the `message.guild.id` property as the variable, and also the one shown on the code.

I'm not sure if you mean what I just suggested, but if so please notify me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and yes, I have used both the `message.guild.id` and the current property with the same error.
But it seems that `var server = bot.guilds.get(message.guild.id).id` did work, I don't know why I didn't realize it sooner. The fix is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem! Hope you have fun continuing with the bot.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds), `bot.guilds` is indexed by each guild's ID. `message.author` is a `User` object, not a guild id. You cannot put a User object into `bot.guilds.get` and expect it to work; it only accepts guild ids.

To get the server that the message was sent in, just do `message.guild`.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that now, after pondering and also from the other answer, thanks for the help, much appreciated.