# How do I list all users with a certain role with the role's ID? I'm using Discord.js Commando

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, commando

I get an error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined'

The command I'm trying to make should list all the users with a certain role in the main server. This is a public bot too so it's in multiple servers. The code I'm currently using is from an answer to a question similar to the one I'm asking.

```
const guild = this.client.guilds.get('498683894489546762');

const allTrusted = guild.roles.get('498686419137724417').members.map(m=>m.user.tag).join('\n');
      const embed = new RichEmbed()
      .setDescription(allTrusteds);      
      msg.say(embed)
```

Comment: `guild` is undefined. Make sure that the ID is correct and that the client is in the desired guild.

Comment: To add to @slothiful 's comment, you may want to consider using the guild of the message that called the command. This may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273185/discord-js-guild-id-is-undefined-even-though-definition-is-there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the question was asked 9 months ago, I still wanted to answer.

Assuming you've updated to djs^12
This is what you should use:

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    msg.guild.members.fetch()
    .then(members => {
        const allTrusteds = members.filter(mmbr => mmbr.roles.cache.get('498686419137724417')).map(m => m.user.tag).join('\n')
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(allTrusteds);
        msg.say(embed);
    });
```