# Blacklisted words | Filter words discord.bs

Tags: api, discord, bots, discord.js

I got one error with my blacklisted words, cannot read proprety ".id" of undefined. After "db.get(...)"

Thanks to help me!

// BLACKLISTED words

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  let wordarray = message.content.split(" ")

  let filterWords = db.get(`blacklistwords_${message.guild.id}_${message.guild.id}`)

  for(var i = 0; 1 < filterWords.length; i++) {
    if(wordarray.includes(filterwords[i])) {
      message.delete()
      let Filter = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#FFE90F')
      .setAuthor(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL())
      .setDescription('<a:AttentionPink:706154679796760657> | **This word is blacklisted from this guild!** Do not say that again!')
      .setTimestamp()
      message.author.send(Filter)
      break;
    }
  }
});![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gouis.jpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your Guild ID in a var like so:

```
var guildID = message.guild.id;
```

If this is not working, well it's not the prettiest, but try using this line of code:

```
var guildID = bot.guilds.get(message.guild.id).id;
```

EDIT: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273185/discord-js-guild-id-is-undefined-even-though-definition-is-there)

Comment: Well this is very strange.. It works 3 times, and after,  it stops working. And i got an error "cannot read propretly .id" of null...

Comment: Look that, here the updated code and the error. https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/655404917363834907/734477525983690892/Screenshot_20200719-202850_Samsung_Internet.jpg    |||   https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/655404917363834907/734477525262008390/Screenshot_20200719-202902_Samsung_Internet.jpg

Answer (score -1):

If the bot receives a message via DMs, it will not be able to get message.guild and that's why it says it is undefined. You can add something like `if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return;` so that the bot will not listen to DMs

Comment: What doesn't work, do you get any error? Where did you put the code I wrote?

Comment: Do you have Discord? If yes, can you send me your tag and your name please?

Comment: Look at the comment on the other helper to see my  updated code and my new error